# Mutar al tipo de dato que se agregó

Tags: c++, poo, polimorfismo, cast

Tengo un array de tipo Persona donde agrego Alumnos y Docentes (estas son derivadas de la clase padre Persona)

```
Persona **aregloPersonas = new Persona *[100];
```

Al momento que quiero ubicar a una persona por su DNI(atributo de Persona) quiero que si encuentre (búsqueda secuencial) el DNI muestre los datos que le corresponden y no solo los de persona, en lo que busqué en la web encontré el método `dynamic_cast<Clase*>` pero tengo que especificar a que tipo de clase tiene que mutar.
¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda mutar al tipo de dato con el que se agregó al array de Personas? ¿O necesariamente tengo que pedir el tipo de objeto que está buscando?

```
case 2:
    //Buscar en el ArrayList
    cout << "Ingrese el dni: ";
    cin >> ubicarDni;
    //Ubicar personas
    posicionArray = Ubicar(aregloPersonas, ubicarDni, nroPeronas);
    if (posicionArray == -1)
    {
        cout << "Persona no ubicada" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Persona ubicada" << endl;
        aregloPersonas[posicionArray]->Mostrar();//MUTAR AL TIPO DE DATO QUE SE AGREGO //
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Para eso justamente se inventaron las funciones-miembro [`virtuales`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda mutar al tipo de dato con el que se agregó al array de Personas?

No, y tiene su por qué.

Piensa que C++ es un lenguaje que soporta varias características bastante complejas:

- Herencia múltiple
- Polimorfismo
- Métodos virtuales

Estas características se soportan gracias a que cada clase guarda información sobre sus propias funciones y miembros. Esto suele hacerse añadiendo información a cada clase en tiempo de compilación.

Es facil comprobarlo con un ejemplo:

```
class A1
{
public:
    void func1();
};

class B1 : public A1
{ };

class A2
{
public:
    virtual void func1();
};

class B2 : public A2
{ };

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(B1) << ' ' << sizeof(B2);
}
```

Lo esperable es que el tamaño de estos objetos sea distinto y el único motivo para ello es que `A2` tiene métodos virtuales. Cuando suceden circunstancias como esta, el compilador es libre de manipular ligermente nuestras clases para dotarlas de los mecanismos que permiten que *"la magia"* se materialice.

Así pues, la triste realidad es que no hay magia por ningún lado, el compilador debe saber en todo momento qué tipos está manejando para que todo funcione correctamente, y eso impide que un tipo pueda ser dos cosas distintas a la vez. Simplemente no hay cabida para eso en C++.

Ahora bien, que eso no se pueda hacer no quiere decir que no haya soluciones. Algunas hay.

Para empezar, como propone @Trauma, puedes usar funciones virtuales ([ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gcy3SQLPZ44cHClk)):

```
class Persona
{
public:
    virtual void Mostrar() const = 0;
};

class Alumno : public Persona
{
    void Mostrar() const override
    { std::cout << "Alumno"; }
};

class Docente : public Persona
{
    void Mostrar() const override
    { std::cout << "Docente"; }
};

int main()
{
    Persona * ptr1 = new Alumno;
    Persona * ptr2 = new Docente;
  
    ptr1->Mostrar();
    std::cout << '\n';
    ptr2->Mostrar();
}
```

A mi personalmente esta solución no me gusta porque no soy partidario de añadir llamadas a `cout` en una función miembro. Básicamente si mañana me pidiesen hacer lo mismo pero guardando los datos en un archivo, tendría que crear una nueva función en cada una de las clases, si luego quiero sacar los datos por consola ... otra función más. Al final acabaría con una clase `Alumno` y una clase `Docente` plagadas de métodos que poco tendrían que ver con la gestión de estas clases.

No obstante, también se puede aprovechar el tipado fuerte de C++ y sobrecargar funciones para extraer este código de las funciones `Alumno` y `Docente`.

En este caso yo optaría por seguir el patrón de diseño [Visitor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)). Lo que hace ahora cada clase `Alumno` y `Profesor` es delegar el comportamiento final en una tercera clase que es la que finalmente saca los datos por pantalla. La ventaja de este enfoque es que podrías visualizar los datos de formas diferentes simplemente heredando de la tercera clase.

En este caso la clase base quedaría así:

```
// declaration forward
class Detalle;

class Persona
{
public:
    virtual void Mostrar(Detalles const&) const = 0;
};
```

Mientras que las implementaciones de la función en `Alumno` y en `Profesor` serían muy similares:

```
void Alumno::Mostrar(Detalles const& detalles) const
{ detalles.Mostrar(*this); }

void Docente::Mostrar(Detalles const& detalles) const
{ detalles.Mostrar(*this); }
```

Lo que se hace aquí es invocar a una función sobrecargada `Detalles::Mostrar`. Esta función tiene varias versiones y una admitirá un objeto de tipo `Alumno` mientras que la otra hará lo propio con una instancia de tipo `Docente`:

```
class Detalles
{
public:
    void Mostrar(Alumno const& alumno) const;
    void Mostrar(Docente const& docente) const;
};
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando ([aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fBJVE8Y6jB02opCN))